# Detect if they leave the app on a specific view

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to detect if my user leaves my app on my specific "GameViewController" and move back to the main view controller. How can check if my user is on the "GameViewController" only and if they leave they are pushed to the main view

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate you can detect your application state, for example didEnterBackground(:*), willResignActive(:*) ...

And from there you can push, pop, present your desire viewController

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground